# What’s wrong with my rig?

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

I have had multiple issues rigging this character. I don't know whether it's the model or the rig itself. I'm using the Rigify add-on, and unfortunately it's not working out for me.

[image]

Can someone show me where I'm messing up? The link at the bottom leads to the file. If you're having issues with the link, please let me know.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N8hZcmPTvLX8xEbaaAAbrQs69gPewixX/view?usp=sharing

Here is an alternate link from MediaFire: https://www.mediafire.com/file/cqkk0z7e2vfh7gm/Izakaru_Stack_Exchange_File.blend/file

Comment: Please use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) to attach .blend files.

Comment: Add some screenshots to show the issues that you have or describe them at least. The question contains not many pieces of information so we have to download a 100MB file and play around to find out what is wrong with it. If your question got closed you can *[edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/223925/edit)* it and chances are good that it gets reopened again. Speaking of [this duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223796/why-do-i-keep-having-rigging-failures).

Comment: After a quick look: The mesh is very dense. A *Decimate* modifier with 2 or 4 un-subdivisions can make it a lot lighter. Also, the mesh is not manifold and consists of several parts. This leads to an error ("bone heat weighting failed") when you try to "Parent with Automatic Weights". If I take your attempt ("Parent With Empty Groups") the feet stick a bit to the ground and the back of the head has problems. This is due to the weight painting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: So how would I go about at making this model more “manifold”? I unsubdivided the model 4 times like you suggested and am happy with the results as the model still in general looks very smooth. But if making the model manifold could also help then I would definitely want to do that.

Comment: People can't help you in comments, not very well.  If you have a question about what makes a mesh manifold or how to fix a problem that shows up on select non manifold operation, you should first do your research, then you should consider asking a new question.  People *will* need your .blend, and you should consider cleaning up the file to the simplest, smallest possible to demonstrate your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A few notes**

The "bone heat weighting failed" error is because your mesh has intersections around the neck, ears, eyes.

Blender comes with an add-on called "Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox". You can enable it in the preferences. Once enabled, it displays a menu in the N-panel in the *Edit* section. If you press the *Check All* button and then the *Intersections* button in *Edit* mode it selects all the faces that intersect. With this add-on, you also can make the mesh manifold so there are no holes in the mesh, such as the open skull for example. (Where is his hair?)

**How to rig the mesh**

Create a copy of the mesh (duplicate), make it manifold with the 3D Print Tools, and make it solid with a *Remesh* modifier. Use *Voxel Size* of 0.04 (depends on the model!), apply the modifier. Alternatively, use remesh in *Sculpt* mode. Then you can parent it *With Automatic Weights* to the *rig* armature and let Blender do the weight painting. The weights are stored in vertex groups which are named like the deform bones. Parent the original mesh *With Empty Groups* to the armature. Then transfer the vertex groups from your copy to the original mesh with a *Data Transfer* modifier (button *Generate Data Layers*, then apply the modifier).

Repeat the transfer steps for the left and right eyes.

Remove the *Armature* modifier from the remeshed copy so it will not deform. You can archive or delete it once you're done.

[image: original mesh and weight paint copy mesh]<sup>original rigged mesh (left) and remeshed copy for weight paint (right), eyes before weight paint transfer (top)</sup>

Optionally, create another copy of the original mesh and send it to an archive collection. Then add a *Decimate* modifier, move it over the *Armature* modifier, and apply it to reduce the number of vertices.

Finally, you need to weight paint the fingers because in the remeshed copy all fingers are joined into one solid hand.

[image: merged fingers]
<sup>merged fingers</sup>

[image: fixed finger]
<sup>manually weight painted, fixed finger</sup>

Comment: His hair isn’t in this file so that the file wouldn’t be so large. But thanks for the feedback. I’m definitely going to look over this.

Comment: It’s not working for me. When I click data transfer, it seems to not affect the model at all in pose mode. The one time it did, it turned out horribly. Can you share your blend file?

Comment: Can I see your blend file so I can see exactly what you did vs what I did?

Comment: Yes sure, however I need to download your file again and do the steps because I probably don't have the blend file no more.

Comment: Ok thank you, seriously. I’m not great at rigging so this is a huge help.

Comment: I've used *Decimate* modifier (2x un-subdivide) to reduce the number of verts and file size to 26MB. Then I've separated the hands, "manifolded" (3D print tools), and remeshed the body. Used the Boolean modifier to join the hands again. The result is the "weight paint dummy". Parented this to the armature, removed it again, parented the original mesh *With Empty Groups*, and finally transfered the weight paints with the *Data Transfer* modifier. Looks all fine, except the file size of 141MB for 150k vertices(?!) I don't know what bloats the file so much.

Comment: @MitchellBradley Here's the blend file. It's still big but compression is activated, 10MB now: https://pasteall.org/blend/3a39d26ce0e248d7890239b33cd0d241 - The left eye has the Data Transfer modifier added but not applied yet so you can check it out. For the final version apply it.  I hope it helps you.